# Python '16+4' input calculator

Tags: python, numbers, calculator

I am trying to find a way to create a calculator where the user can input 
`6+8` for example and get an answer.

I'm trying to find a better way to get it to work for numbers of more than one digit or a function for it to work for anything.

Below is my code so far.

```
calc = input("Enter the calculation ")
nums = []
for i in calc: # Only works for single-digit numbers eg: 6+6
    try:
        if i != " ":
            float(i)
    except ValueError:
        op = str(i)

lcalc = len(calc)
if lcalc == 3:
    calc2 = calc[0]
    calc3 = calc[2]
    nums.append(int(calc2))
    nums.append(int(calc3))
elif lcalc == 5:
    calc2 = calc[0:2]
    calc3 = calc[3:5]
    nums.append(int(calc2))
    nums.append(int(calc3))
elif lcalc == 7:
    calc2 = calc[0:3]
    calc3 = calc[4:7]
    nums.append(int(calc2))
    nums.append(int(calc3))

print(nums)

if op == "+":
    print("Final answer = " +str(sum(nums)))
elif op == "-":
    print("Final answer = " +str(nums[0] - nums[1]))
elif op == "/":
    print("Final answer = " +str(nums[0] / nums[1]))
elif op == "*":
    print("Final answer = " +str(nums[0] * nums[1]))
```

Comment: Please, if my answer was right and helpful accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is:

```
calc = input("Enter the calculation: ")
print("Final answer:", eval(calc))
```

Explanation: when you enter `6+8` it's also python expression and `eval()` returns result of python expression.

But user can type any python expression (like `quit()` or something with strings).

So better answer would be:

```
calc = input("Enter the calculation: ")

calc = calc.replace(" ", "")

m_i = calc.find("*")
m_i = len(calc) if m_i == -1 else m_i
d_i = calc.find("/")
d_i = len(calc) if d_i == -1 else d_i
while m_i < len(calc) or d_i < len(calc):
    i = min(m_i, d_i)
    p_i = calc.rfind("+", 0, i)
    s_i = calc.rfind("-", 0, i)
    val1_i = max(p_i, s_i)
    val1 = int(calc[val1_i + 1:i])
    p_i = calc.find("+", i)
    p_i = len(calc) if p_i == -1 else p_i
    s_i = calc.find("-", i)
    s_i = len(calc) if s_i == -1 else s_i
    val2_i = min(p_i, s_i)
    val2 = int(calc[i + 1:val2_i])
    if i == m_i:
        ans = str(val1 * val2)
    else:
        ans = str(val1 // val2)
    calc = calc.replace(calc[val1_i + 1:val2_i], ans, 1)
    m_i = calc.find("*")
    m_i = len(calc) if m_i == -1 else m_i
    d_i = calc.find("/")
    d_i = len(calc) if d_i == -1 else d_i


val = 0
t = "+"
i = -1
for p, x in enumerate(calc):
    if x in "+-":
        v = int(calc[i + 1:p])
        if t == "+":
            val += v
        else:
            val -= v
        i = p
        t = x
v = int(calc[i + 1:])
if t == "+":
    val += v
else:
    val -= v

print("Final answer:", val)
```

So first line is like in previous way. Line:

```
calc = calc.replace(" ", "")
```

Replaces all spaces in string with empty string (so it deletes it).

```
m_i = calc.find("*")
m_i = len(calc) if m_i == -1 else m_i
d_i = calc.find("/")
d_i = len(calc) if d_i == -1 else d_i
```

finds earliest `/` and `*` if none found set them to end of string,

```
while m_i < len(calc) or d_i < len(calc):
    i = min(m_i, d_i)
```

loop that executes while multiplication or division signs are found, `i` is earlier of signs,

```
p_i = calc.rfind("+", 0, i)
s_i = calc.rfind("-", 0, i)
val1_i = max(p_i, s_i)
val1 = int(calc[val1_i + 1:i])
```

finds value of left operand (first finds last `+` and last `-` sign, higher of these two plus one is starting index of left operand).

Lines:

```
p_i = calc.find("+", i)
p_i = len(calc) if p_i == -1 else p_i
s_i = calc.find("-", i)
s_i = len(calc) if s_i == -1 else s_i
val2_i = min(p_i, s_i)
val2 = int(calc[i + 1:val2_i])
```

are very similar to previous ones, except they finds right operand.

```
if i == m_i:
    ans = str(val1 * val2)
else:
    ans = str(val1 // val2)
calc = calc.replace(calc[val1_i + 1:val2_i], ans, 1)
```

Calculates result of multiplication or division (I wrote `//` because I think you want integer division) and replaces expression with result.

Last lines of loop are same as lines before loop so I won't explain them.

In last loop `t` is operator and if it's `+`, `val` will increase for last value, otherwise it will decrease.

Last line just prints final value.

**Note:** using regular expression (`re`) can help a lot, especially if you add brackets, power, and similar.